# Iterar dos arreglos (Forward y Bidireccional) en lenguaje C

Tags: array, c, bucles, iteradores

Qué tal, soy nuevo en C y tengo un problema con la implementación de iteraciones, ya que al mismo tiempo debe de haber una función genérica, este es el código al que he llegado hasta ahora, definí dos funciones génericas que son las iteraciones que quiero realizar, Forward y Bidirectional:

```
    /*Funciones genericas 
void recorre();

void forward();
void bidirectional();*/

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void series(int opcion){
    
     numero * serie;
    numero * aux;
    
    int cantidad = 0;
    
    printf(" ¿ Cuantos numeros quieres guardar ? : ");
    scanf("%d", &cantidad);
    
    serie = (numero *) malloc(sizeof(numero) * cantidad);
    
    numero * final = serie + cantidad;
    
    for (aux = serie; aux < final; ++aux) {
        
       
        printf(" Ingrese el valor del numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &aux->valor);
        
    }
    
    printf("\n\n---Serie de numeros ---\n\n");
    
   /* recorre(&forward, series, sizeof(series),cantidad);*/
    
    for (aux = serie; aux < final; ++aux) {
        printf("%4d \n",
               aux->valor);
    }
}

void bibliotecas(int opcion)
{
    libro * biblioteca;
    libro * aux;
    
    int cantidad = 0;
    
    printf(" ¿ Cuantos libros quieres guardar? : ");
    scanf("%d", &cantidad);
    
    biblioteca = (libro *) malloc(sizeof(libro) * cantidad);
    
    libro * final = biblioteca + cantidad;
    
    for (aux = biblioteca; aux < final; ++aux) {
        
        aux->titulo = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
        
        printf("Entre el titulo del libro: ");
        scanf("%s", aux->titulo);

        
        printf("Entre el numero de paginas del libro: ");
        scanf("%d", &aux->paginas);
        
    }
    /*recorre(&Bidirectional, bibliotecas, sizeof(bibliotecas), cantidad)*/
    
    printf("\n\n--- Listado de libros ---\n\n");
    for (aux = biblioteca; aux < final; ++aux) {
        printf("%25s \t %4d \n",
               aux->titulo,
               aux->paginas);
    }
    
}
/*
void forward(void *series){
}

void bidirectional(void *bibliotecas){
}*/
```

Agradecería si me pudieran ayudar o enseñar a elaborar una implementación correcta de estos dos tipos de iteraciones, Forward y Bidirectional. Las funciones genéricas están vacías porque tenía los valores equivocados y me marcaba error, topé pared con las iteraciones, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: No existe una implementación genérica de iteradores porque C no lo permite debido a sus carencias. Es un lenguaje muy simple en el que el compilador se limita a transcribir código (no hay metadatos, tabla de funciones virtuales, ...) puedes intentar emular ese comportamiento pero a costa de escribir mucho código (todo el que mantienen otros compiladores a la sombra sin que te enteres). Yo en tu lugar abandonaría, como tarea inmediata, la creación de un iterador genérico y probaría a crear iteradores específicos... cuando tengas varios iteradores diferentes podrás ir sacando funcionalidad común

Comment: Falta detalles en esta pregunta, ¿a que te refieres con forward y bidireccional? ¿Qué resultado esperas? ¿Quieres hacer un iterador así como en otros lenguajes como por ejemplo en Java?